# Coin flips and Winning

Tags: probability

I keep seeing questions similar to this in interviews and although I can intuitively reach an answer, I do not know how to formally reach it. Say I start with 1 dollar and my opponent starts with 2 dollars. A coin is flipped and if it lands heads, I lose a dollar, and if it lands tails, my opponent loses a dollar. What is the probability that I win? I intuitively say it is 1/3, but do not know how I reach that conclusion.

EDIT
A person who wins is the last one with any money remaining. So if someone reaches 0 dollars, they lose. The money is not given to the opponent, only subtracted from the balance.

Comment: What is the condition for winning? Is it that the other player has no money?

Comment: Note: I assume that "win" means "winds up with all the money" but it should be clarified.

Comment: The edit still doesn't resolve all the confusion.  For instance, in my solution, I assume that any dollar you win (or lose) comes from (or goes to) your opponent.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Please edit your post to explain the problem clearly and completely.  Just to be sure:  Nobody ever wins any money?  You are just asking for the probability that you throw $2$ Tails before you throw $1$ Head?

Comment: The Wikipedia plot summary for [Gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) is reasonably informative.

Comment: Another question is obviously, is the coin a fair coin? If you have a coin with two heads or two tails, that significantly changes the probability (0% chance to win the former and 100% chance for the latter). If you have a coin that is specifically designed to flip one side more frequently than the other, that would also change the ultimate probability.

Answer (score 4):

Interpretation I:

If the question is asking "throwing a fair coin sequentially, what is the probability that $2$ Tails are thrown  before a single Head , the answer is clearly $$\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 14$$ as the only winning scenario is to throw $TT$.

It seems unlikely to me that this is really the intended question, though, so I will leave up my other solution which is based on a different set of rules.  In this version, getting $H$ means your opponent gives you $1$ dollar, and throwing a $T$ means you give your opponent $1$ dollar.

Interpretation II:

I assume that each dollar won (or lost) comes from or goes to your opponent and I assume that  "win" means "winds up with all $3$ dollars".

Let $P_n$ denote the probability that you win given that you currently have $n$ dollars.  Thus the answer you want is $P_1$.

We remark that $$P_0=0\quad P_3=1$$ $$ P_1=\frac 12\times P_0+\frac 12\times P_2=\frac 12\times P_2$$ $$ P_2=\frac 12\times P_3+\frac 12\times P_1=\frac 12\times \left( 1+ P_1\right)$$

Combining the last two equations we see that $$P_1=\frac 12\times \frac 12\times \left( 1+ P_1\right)\implies 4P_1=1+P_1\implies P_1=\frac 13$$

Just as you intuited (though I should say that intuition in these matters is not terribly reliable, as a rule).

Comment: It's not clear to me from the specification of the problem that the other player will get the dollar that one player loses. Then the problem is just "winning a coin flip twice in a row."

Comment: @platty  I agree the problem is phrased poorly.  I think that my interpretation is sensible...indeed, the only one I can think of that leads to an interesting problem.  Of course the OP ought to clarify.

Comment: @plattty  it seems you are right.  I'll edit my solution in light of the clarification.

Comment: If $P_T$ is the probability of flipping tails and $P_H=1-P_T$ is the probability of flipping heads, then you can write the final probabilities as: $$P_T^2$$ for Interpretation 1 and $$P_1 = \dfrac{P_T^2}{1-P_T+P_T^2}$$ for Interpretation 2 which if $P_T=\dfrac{1}{2}$ gives $\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $\dfrac{1}{3}$ respectively as in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

That you win the coin toss?  Why isn't it 50/50? One coin flip, two sides, has to come down on one side or the other - landing on an edge is pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $P(A)$=$P(``I\,win'')$. Then $P(A)=(1/2)*(1/2)+(1/2)*(1/2)*P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming winning means an opponent has no money and you get the $\$1$ he loses, you can only stand a deficit of one loss while your opponent has to have a deficit of two losses.

The sequence where you win is:

WW, WLWW, WLWLWW,...... etc

So $P_w = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}^2 + \frac{1}{4}^3 ........ \frac{1}{4}^{\infty}$

$P_w = S = \frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{(\frac{1}{4})}{(\frac{3}{4})} = \frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

The only way you win is if there are two tails in a row (as soon as there are any heads, you lose), so your probability of winning is 0.25.

If the loser of each coin flip gives the dollar to the other person, then your intuition would be correct: whoever wins the whole game will end up with three dollars. Since the expected value of (your money after a coin flip) is the same as your money before the coin flip, your expected value of (money at the end of the game) should be one dollar. So your probability of winning times the money you end up with if you win has to be the same as your current money, so $3p=1$ and hence $p=\frac13$.